# DropDownListFor on a static list of states

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I swear I am having one hell of a time trying to populate a DropDownList from a static list of States.  I would prefer that this list be pre-populated from the db via EntityFramework.

My RegisterViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "The username can only be comprised of letters.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The Password and Confirmed Password don't match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid E-mail Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid E-mail Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Email")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The Email Address and Confirmed Email don't match")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty")]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "First name can only be comprised of letters.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Last name can only be comprised of letters.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int ZipCode { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

}
```

The StaticList of States?

```
public static class StaticLists
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> States = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Alabama", Value = "AL"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Alaska", Value = "AK"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Arizona", Value = "AZ"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Arkansas", Value = "AR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "California", Value = "CA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Colorado", Value = "CO"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Connecticut", Value = "CT"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "District of Columbia", Value = "DC"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Delaware", Value = "DE"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Florida", Value = "FL"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Georgia", Value = "GA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Hawaii", Value = "HI"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Idaho", Value = "ID"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Illinois", Value = "IL"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Indiana", Value = "IN"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Iowa", Value = "IA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Kansas", Value = "KS"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Kentucky", Value = "KY"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Louisiana", Value = "LA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Maine", Value = "ME"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Maryland", Value = "MD"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Massachusetts", Value = "MA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Michigan", Value = "MI"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Minnesota", Value = "MN"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Mississippi", Value = "MS"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Missouri", Value = "MO"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Montana", Value = "MT"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Nebraska", Value = "NE"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Nevada", Value = "NV"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "New Hampshire", Value = "NH"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "New Jersey", Value = "NJ"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "New Mexico", Value = "NM"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "New York", Value = "NY"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "North Carolina", Value = "NC"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "North Dakota", Value = "ND"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Ohio", Value = "OH"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Oklahoma", Value = "OK"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Oregon", Value = "OR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Pennsylvania", Value = "PA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Rhode Island", Value = "RI"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "South Carolina", Value = "SC"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "South Dakota", Value = "SD"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Tennessee", Value = "TN"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Texas", Value = "TX"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Utah", Value = "UT"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Vermont", Value = "VT"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Virginia", Value = "VA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Washington", Value = "WA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "West Virginia", Value = "WV"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Wisconsin", Value = "WI"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Wyoming", Value = "WY"}
    };
}
```

I was thinking of creating a class called, "Static Lists" but now I figure it's better to just have this as a property in my RegisterViewModel?

Can I just combine the following?

```
public List<ListOfStates> State {get;set;}
public List<string> ListOfStates {get;set;}
```

I tried passing a ViewBag item from the Controller but I wasn't very successful...Nothing in my view now

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.ListOfStates = StaticLists.States;

        return View();
    }
```

This is what the view looks like, again Here is what my View looks like, again, can't figure out how to populate the list...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, ViewBag.ListOfStates)
```

Getting some runtime errors

```
"as no applicable method named DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched....."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it, if anyone is having the same issue.

The static class

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateListItems()
    {
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Alabama", Value = "AL"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Alaska", Value = "AK"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Arizona", Value = "AZ"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Arkansas", Value = "AR"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "California", Value = "CA"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Colorado", Value = "CO"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Connecticut", Value = "CT"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "District of Columbia", Value = "DC"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Delaware", Value = "DE"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Florida", Value = "FL"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Georgia", Value = "GA"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Hawaii", Value = "HI"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Idaho", Value = "ID"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Illinois", Value = "IL"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Indiana", Value = "IN"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Iowa", Value = "IA"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Kansas", Value = "KS"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Kentucky", Value = "KY"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Louisiana", Value = "LA"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Maine", Value = "ME"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Maryland", Value = "MD"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Massachusetts", Value = "MA"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Michigan", Value = "MI"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Minnesota", Value = "MN"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Mississippi", Value = "MS"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Missouri", Value = "MO"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Montana", Value = "MT"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Nebraska", Value = "NE"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Nevada", Value = "NV"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "New Hampshire", Value = "NH"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "New Jersey", Value = "NJ"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "New Mexico", Value = "NM"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "New York", Value = "NY"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "North Carolina", Value = "NC"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "North Dakota", Value = "ND"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Ohio", Value = "OH"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Oklahoma", Value = "OK"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Oregon", Value = "OR"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Pennsylvania", Value = "PA"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Rhode Island", Value = "RI"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "South Carolina", Value = "SC"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "South Dakota", Value = "SD"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Tennessee", Value = "TN"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Texas", Value = "TX"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Utah", Value = "UT"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Vermont", Value = "VT"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Virginia", Value = "VA"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Washington", Value = "WA"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "West Virginia", Value = "WV"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Wisconsin", Value = "WI"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Wyoming", Value = "WY"}
        };
        return items;
    }
```

In my view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, SP.BLL.StaticLists.StateListItems(), "Select Your     State", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Hi Spets, Thank you very much for posting your solution - it worked perfectly for me also and saved a ton of work!  I'm using VS2015 and modified a field, originally created in a scaffold generated view, with your code.  Not often a solution is so clean and complete.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to pass it into the View Model instead the ViewBag?. You could do this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, Model.ListOfStates)
```

ADDED:

Your problem is that you are forming incorrectly your static property. It should be this:

```
  public static List<SelectListItem> States
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>() {
              new SelectListItem() {Text = "Alabama", Value = "AL"},
              new SelectListItem() {Text = "Alaska", Value = "AK"},
              new SelectListItem() {Text = "Arizona", Value = "AZ"},
```

Comment: Idk but doing that wont' work, the Model(RegisterViewModel) doesn't know what ListOfStates property is(I dont have that declared anywhere in the class

Comment: Didn't work, got a runtime error converting from List<SelectListItem> to IEnumerable<SelectListItems>